# Is there a way to remove brushes from the brush browser?

Tags: brushes

It's surprisingly hard to find any info about this and it has only led to me accidentally creating more and more duplicates

[image]

Comment: Maybe in the outliner change the mode to "Blender File" and there look into "Brushes". Or, since it looks like your brushes aren't marked as protected ("fake single user"), you can use "Orphan Data" instead, there mark the brushes you want to keep as protected ("fake single user" shield icon) and then remove orphans.

Comment: @Markus von Broady I guess you can write this as an answer, weird that they didn't create a simple remove button

Answer (score 0):

1. Turn off "Fake user" [image] for each brush you want to remove, you can do it by choosing each brush in the "Active Tool and Workspace Settings" [image] and clicking the shield icon, or later in step 4.
2. Make sure none of the brushes you want to delete remain chosen as the active brush.
3. In the *Outliner* switch the mode to *Orphan Data*.
4. If you haven't done so already, disable the shield icons for the brushes you want to delete by clicking on the shield icons [image].
5. Click the "Purge" button.

[image]